# applying linear filters to images ( implementing imfilter) without influencing speed and performance

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, time

Based on [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672184/implementing-imfilter-in-matlab) and [this one](http://angeljohnsy.blogspot.com/2011/04/matlab-code-for-linear-filtering.html) I'm familiar with implementing imfilter function.But as you know these kind of codes( using sequential for loops) would be very slow in matlab specially for high resolution images and they are more efficient in other programming languages. In matlab it's better to vectorize your code as much as possible.
Can anyone suggest me a way for vectorizing imfilter implementation?
Note: I know that I can use edit('imfilter') to study the code that developers have used for implementing imfilter function but it's pretty hard for me. I don't understand much of the codes. I'm pretty new to matlab.
Note: I know that some part of the codes introduced as an example could be vectorized very easily fore example padding section in [this code](http://angeljohnsy.blogspot.com/2011/04/matlab-code-for-linear-filtering.html) could be implemented more easily.
But I'm thinking of a away for vectorizing the main part of the code (part of applying the filter). I mean the parts that are shown in the pictures:
[image]
[image]
I don't know how to vectorize these parts?
Oh, I forgot to tell that I have written the accepted answer for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672184/implementing-imfilter-in-matlab) Is there any way if I also don't want to use conv2 function?

Comment: Article from The MathWorks [on vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). See also this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867901/introduction-to-vectorizing-in-matlab-any-good-tutorials).

Answer (score 3):

There is a function just for you... it's called `im2col`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html for a description. It allows you to turn "blocks" of the image into "columns" - if you are looking for 3x3 blocks to filter, each column will be 9 elements long. After that, the filter operation can be very simple.  Here is an example:

```
n = 20; m = 30
myImg = rand(n, m)*255;
myImCol = im2col(myImg, [3 3], 'sliding');
myFilter = [1 2 1 2 4 2 1 2 1]';
myFilter = myFilter / sum(myFilter(:)); % to normalize
filteredImage = reshape( myImCol' * myFilter, n-2, m-2);
```

Didn't use `conv2`, and didn't use any explicit loops. This does, however, create an intermediate matrix which is a good deal bigger than the image (in this case, almost 9x). That could be a problem in its own right.

Disclaimer: I usually test Matlab code before posting, but could not connect to the license server. Let me know if you run into issues!

**edit** some further clarifications for you

1) Why reshape with `n-2` and `m-2`? Well - the im2col function only returns "complete" columns for the blocks that it can create. When I create 3x3 blocks, the first one I can make is centered on (2,2), and the last one on (end-1, end-1). Thus the result is a bit smaller than the original image- it's "like padding". This is in fact the exact opposite of what happens when you use `conv2` - in that case things get expanded. If you want to avoid that you could first expand your image with

```
paddedIm = zeros(n+2, m+2);
paddedIm(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = myImg;
```

and run the filter on the padded image.

2) The difference between `'sliding'` and `'distinct'` is best explained with an example:

```
>> M = magic(4)

M =

16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1

>> im2col(M,[2 2], 'distinct')

ans =

 16     9     3     6
  5     4    10    15
  2     7    13    12
 11    14     8     1

xx--  --xx  ----  ----
xx--  --xx  ----  ----
----  ----  xx--  --xx
----  ----  xx--  --xx

>> im2col(M,[2 2], 'sliding')

ans =

 16     5     9     2    11     7     3    10     6
  5     9     4    11     7    14    10     6    15
  2    11     7     3    10     6    13     8    12
 11     7    14    10     6    15     8    12     1

xx--  ----  ----  -xx-
xx--  xx--  ----  -xx-      ... etc ...
----  xx--  xx--  ----
----  ----  xx--  ----
```

As you can see, the `'distinct'` option returns non-overlapping blocks: the `'sliding'` option returns "all blocks that fit" even though some will overlap.

3) The implementation of `conv2` is likely some lower level code for speed - you may know about `.mex` files which allow you to write your own C code that can be linked with Matlab and gives you a big speed advantage? This is likely to be something like that. They do claim on their website that they use a "straightforward implementation" - so the speed is most likely just a matter of implementing in a fast manner (not "efficient Matlab").

Comment: nice to know about this function

Comment: very good way!!! but some questions rose up they are lengthy enough that I can't ask in this comment. Could I chat with you @Floris

Comment: Unfortunately I am behind a firewall and can't chat right now. Maybe if you are around later I can try to connect.

Comment: Well @Floris it seems that I can't.The questions are 1-Why do you use m-2 and n-2 for reshaping the filtered image should be of the same size as the original one! is it because of zero padding?but the sliding method doesn't do any zero padding!2-I didn't understand difference between distinct and sliding methods clearly. could you guide me? 3-I although thought of studying edit('conv2') to understand how this function is implemented but in matlab R2010a I encountered only the comments of this m-file not the implementation. Do you know anyway studying this function's implementation on the net

Comment: I have tried to address your questions by editing the answer. See also http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html for algorithm used.

Comment: thanks for your introducing [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) @Floris. But this algoriyhm is also accessible by matlab's local help. I don't want the documentation, I want to see the code for implementation of conv2. Do you know anyway of finding this on the net?

Comment: No I am not aware they publish this code - you could ask them? Are you looking for something more efficient than my example?

Comment: Dear @Floris the code that you suggested is really excellent especially because of that MATLAB® is optimized for operations involving matrices and vectors and I know there's no need to look for codes alot and you can use built-in functions. But eventually I found something that is more near to my purpose. At this time I can't upload the code but I will post it soon. But your suggestion and Adiel's each introduce different aspects of vectorizing based on [this web page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) and are so useful. keep them in the post,please

Answer (score 1):

The two inner loops can be vectorized by-

```
orignalFlip=flipud(fliplr(orignal(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1)));
temp=orignalFlip.*filter;
```

but what the problem with 'conv2' ? seems that exactly what you need...

However, you should not doing 4 nested-loops in matlab.

Comment: Well this is a college assignment. I should not use built-in functions in matlab(built-ins that do exactly what I want) as much as possible. And you know that speed of this code is more influenced by two outer loops. I thought about the way of reshaping the original image into a nx1 vector. Do you think it would help me with combination of codes that you suggested get rid of two outer for loops?

Comment: Look on Floris answer, it's seems a useful solution. you can evaluate the r matrix before reshape in last line