# Matlab - Image Filtering with a 5X5 Filter without imfilter function

Tags: matlab

I tried to modify the code ([Implementing IMFILTER in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672184/implementing-imfilter-in-matlab/50012382#50012382)) to filter an image with an 5X5 gaussian filter. Something is wrong but I don't find it.

```
     gauss_kernel = fspecial('gaussian',5,2);
        function [result] = evc_filter(input, kernel)


        rsize = size(input);

        r = zeros(rsize);

        original=padarray(input,[2,2]);

        for i = 3:rsize(1)+2
            for j = 3:rsize(2)+2           
                temp = original(i-2:i+2,j-2:j+2) .* kernel;
                r(i-2,j-2) = sum(temp(:));
            end
        end
result=r;
end
```

If I display the picture with imshow it looks different if I use the imfilter function. Can anyone help?

Comment: how is your kernel defined?

Comment: fspecial('gaussian',5,2);

Comment: convert your image to double using double(original), then do the remaining procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but nothing change on the result picture

Comment: You never define `result` in your function. Is this because of copy-pasting from your code to this post?

Comment: Yes, I forgot it. in my code in matlab der ist the line result=r;

Comment: Also, a 5x5 sampling of a Gaussian kernel with sigma=2 does not lead to a proper Gaussian kernel. You're cutting off the tails, makes it no longer Gaussian. I wrote [a blog post about this](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/695) some years ago. You're cutting off at 1 x sigma (leftmost graph in the blog post).

Comment: Thanks for the link to your blog post but thats the excerise I have to do. It looks interesting I will read it if I have solved the problem :)

Comment: @Bea140592: If this is your exercise, you're being taught bad stuff. You should complain to your professor. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, convert your image to double then do the remaining procedure. see example code below:

```
function imfilt()
img = imread('one.jpg');
img = double(img);
[r,c,z] = size(img);
pad = 4;
nimg = zeros(r+pad,c+pad,z);
nimg(pad/2+1: r+pad/2, pad/2+1: c+pad/2,:) = img;
h = fspecial('gaussian',5,2);

res = zeros(r,c,z);
for i = pad/2+1 : r+pad/2
    for j = pad/2+1 : c+pad/2
        tmp = nimg(i-pad/2:i+pad/2,j-pad/2:j+pad/2,1).*h;
        res(i-pad/2,j-pad/2,1) = sum(tmp(:));
        tmp = nimg(i-pad/2:i+pad/2,j-pad/2:j+pad/2,2).*h;
        res(i-pad/2,j-pad/2,2) = sum(tmp(:));
        tmp = nimg(i-pad/2:i+pad/2,j-pad/2:j+pad/2,3).*h;
        res(i-pad/2,j-pad/2,3) = sum(tmp(:));
    end
end

imshow(uint8(res),[]);
end
```

Comment: I have tried it with your example code and change it to my variables but I get an error message

Comment: Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Comment: you might have not initialized some variable properly.

Comment: I have only changed this line: img = double(input);

Comment: what is size of input and kernel?

Comment: input = 512x512x3 double and kernel = 5x5

Comment: then convert your input to grayscale image first using rgb2gray() because this example is for grayscale image.

Comment: Ok, problem is I need the colors. I should get the same result like imfilter(image, gauss_kernel). Do you have a hint what I have to change to geht a rgb picture